# Change UI when values in SQLite are changed by an IntentService

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an `Intent service` running in background which changes some values stored in `SQLite` database of the device. There is an activity opened in foreground which is visible to the user.
The activity shows some values to the user and those values are being altered by the `Intent Service`.
How can I change those values and sync them with `SQLite` without asking the user to refresh the activity?

Android OS: Oreo

Comment: You can register the Broadcast to communicate with the service.

Comment: Best to use livedata. No manual handling required.

Answer (score 0):

There several ways to achieve this, one of them is using interface.

**In service**:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
   private Callbacks callback;

   //Other codes
   //.....

   callback.updateClient(data) //trigger interface callback in appropriate place

   //Other codes
   //.....
   public interface Callbacks{ //define interface according to your need 
     public void updateClient(long data);
   }
}
```

**In activity:**

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyService.Callbacks{
       @Override
       public void updateClient(long data) {
         // change UI 
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app I run service to update widget, start service in MainActivity:

```
private void startService() {
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoadQuotesService.class));
    }
```

***Class LoadQuotesService***

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
public class LoadQuotesService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver alarm = new AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver();
        alarm.SetAlarm(getBaseContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";
    private DatabaseQuoteHelper databaseQuoteHelper;
    private QuoteBusiness quoteBusiness;
    private final String TAG = "AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        databaseQuoteHelper = DatabaseQuoteHelper.newInstance(context);
        quoteBusiness = QuoteBusiness.newInstance(context);
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        assert pm != null;
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
        wakeLock.acquire(10 * 60 * 1000L /*10 minutes*/);

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)) {
            stringBuilder.append("One time Timer : ");
        }
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        stringBuilder.append(formatter.format(new Date()));
        new GetRandomQuote().execute();
        wakeLock.release();
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class GetRandomQuote extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            quoteBusiness.getListQuote(Api.GET_LIST_QUOTES_BY_TREND + "NEW/50", new IQuoteListener() {
                @Override
                public void start() {
                }

                @Override
                public void result(List<Quote> quoteList) {
                    if (databaseQuoteHelper.getAllQuotes().size() > 0) {
                        databaseQuoteHelper.deleteAllData();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < quoteList.size(); i++) {
                        Quote quote = quoteList.get(i);
                        databaseQuoteHelper.insertQuote(quote);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void nil(String message) {
                }

                @Override
                public void error(String err) {

                }
            });

            return null;
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("ShortAlarm")
    public void SetAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        assert am != null;
        int ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), ONE_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }

    public void CancelAlarm(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        assert alarmManager != null;
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }

    public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        assert am != null;
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
    }
}
```

**When load data done i show in my widget:**

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
            DatabaseQuoteHelper databaseQuoteHelper = DatabaseQuoteHelper.newInstance(context);
            List<Quote> quoteList = databaseQuoteHelper.getAllQuotes();

            if (!quoteList.isEmpty()) {
                Random random = new Random();
                int rdIndex = random.nextInt(quoteList.size() - 1);
                CharSequence quoteContent = quoteList.get(rdIndex).getQuoteContentVN();
                CharSequence authorName = quoteList.get(rdIndex).getQuoteAuthorName();
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_TvQuoteContent, quoteContent);
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_textAuthorName, authorName);
            } else {
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_TvQuoteContent, context.getString(R.string.not_quote_save));
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_textAuthorName, context.getString(R.string.app_name));
            }

            Intent refresh = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
            refresh.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
            refresh.putExtra("appWidgetIds", appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pendingIntentRefresh = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, refresh, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetBtnReload, pendingIntentRefresh);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

**It's work fine, hope this help!**